# How to normalize column values in new column?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-aggregation

I've below data in table, `val1,val2,val3` are of double type. `x` represents record is having old value and `y` represents new value. So we need to concatenate all double values in respective col `(oldVal,newVal)` based on x and y value

```
ID,region,status,val1,val2,val3
1, aa,    x,    10,  11,  13
1, aa,    y,    12,  14,  15
2, bb,    x,    null,  null,  null
2, bb,    y,    null,  null,  null
```

expected output, oldVal,newVal are of varchar type

```
ID,region,oldVal,newVal
1, aa,10-11-13, 12-14-15
1, bb,null, null
```

how to de-normalize can be done for this to get expected output ?

Note: If any of the value is null out of `(val1, val2, val3)`, then null value should not be considered.

```
1,2,null > 1-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the condition aggregate function with `CONCAT_WS` function.

```
SELECT ID,
       region,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'x' THEN CONCAT_WS('-',val1,val2,val3) END) oldVal,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'y' THEN CONCAT_WS('-',val1,val2,val3) END) newVal
FROM T
GROUP BY ID,region
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8adf2464fc1fb8fd2a9e6144383b1897)

Comment: what's a purpose of Max ?

Comment: @OxanaGrey The purpose of `Max` is for condition aggregate function.